# Extending lvm with space from another lvm

Tags: lvm, storage

I have two logical volumes.

```
                             Size  Used  Avail  Use%  Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_name-lv_root  38G   5.3G  24G    19%
tmpfs                        1.1G  420K  1.1G    1%   /dev/shm
/dev/sda1                    485M  48M   412M   11%   /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_name-lv_home   29G  210M  28G     1%   /home
```

How can I extend my logical volume `lv_home`, taking space from `lv_root`?

I tried `lvextend -L +1G /dev/vg_name/lv_home`.

It gives me this error:

> Insufficient free space: 256 extents needed, but only 0 available

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use space from `lv_root`, you need to shrink it. This is only possible (without reformatting) if the file system you’re using supports shrinking; ext3/ext4 are fine, [XFS isn’t (in this regard)](http://www.xfs.org/index.php/Shrinking_Support).

The appropriate tool is `lvreduce`:

```
lvreduce -r -L -1G /dev/vg_name/lv_root
```

The `-r` options instructs it to use `fsadm` to resize the file system before shrinking the LV. Once it finishes, you’ll have enough free space in your VG to extend your home LV.

Comment: sometimes the root is the volume group which own the space and is not unmountable during the usage of the OS. running a live OS (run directly from usb pen) is possible to overcome the issue. my 50 cents.